# sitecore, Master Db, template set field source from Core Db

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have an template in Master DB. For one of its field, of type "Droplink", I want to set source from Core DB (/sitecore/system/Field types/Simple Types).

So that I can get this list for droplink selection in Content Editor. I don't know if its possible to access some thing like this from Master Db.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `databasename=SOME_DATABASE_NAME&datasource=SOME_ITEM_PATH`

E.g.:

```
databasename=core&datasource=/sitecore/system/Field types/Simple Types
```

[image: sitecore field source from another database]